# AWS javascript sdk fleet provisioning ResourceNotFound exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am trying to implement fleet provisioning in AWS Lambda function. As a starting point, I have this code:

```js
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var iot = new AWS.Iot({ 
    endpoint: 'apiendpoint',
    accessKeyId: "AAAABBBBBCCCCDDDDD",
    secretAccessKey: "AAAAABBBBCCCDD/1234122311222",
    region: 'ap-south-1'
});


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var params = {
        setAsActive: true
    };
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body:JSON.stringify(await createCertAndKey(params))
    }       
    
}

const createCertAndKey = async (params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        iot.createKeysAndCertificate(params, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                reject(err)
            }
            else{
                console.log("success?");
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I get a `ResourceNotFound` exception for calling `createKeysAndCertificate`. I also tried calling other functions of iot, but it gives the same exception.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: we don't need to pass `endpoint` , try taking it off.

Comment: Yes it worked when I removed endpoint. Thanks @BaluVyamajala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

endpoint passed when intialzing an object should be generic AWS service in format `https://{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com`. we don't need to pass it, AWS will assume based on region and object we are initializing.

```
var iot = new AWS.Iot({ 
    endpoint: 'iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
    accessKeyId: "AAAABBBBBCCCCDDDDD",
    secretAccessKey: "AAAAABBBBCCCDD/1234122311222",
    region: 'ap-south-1'
});
```